VSCode, how to type tab in the search and replace box
In Mac VSCode, I have files with a lot of \t in it. I want to replace all of them with actual tab.
However, I don't know how to type the tab in the replace box.
Anyone know how? Thanks!

PS: I will also accept command line solution that I can just pipe it to a new file.

Are you actually using tabs? Some times VSC uses 4 spaces for indentation, then replacing \t with 4 spaces should do the trick

I am trying to replace actual characters sequence "\t" with actual tabs in the file.

You can use the Regular expression option for this:

So search for a \t, but we need to escape \ so it's not searching for an actual tab, but the string itself, so it becomes \\t.
Replace with a tab \t, since we've enabled regular expression, this will be the actual tab.

That works! Thank you!
